# Convert dataset in report Builder to Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have this report in Report builder and i am asked to move it to power bi. My problem Is that Dont know what kind of data source that was use.
[image]

I tried Power BI web, Jason and xml non work.
Any Idea how i can import the data?
Thanks

Comment: That looks like a semantic query on and Analysis Services Model (SSAS Multi dimensional)